# нужно сократить время выполнения

Tags: python

вот сама задача

Объединение последовательностей
Даны две бесконечных возрастающих последовательности чисел A и B. i-ый член последовательности A равен i<sup>2</sup>. i-ый член последовательности B равен i<sup>3</sup>.

Требуется найти C<sub>x</sub>, где C — возрастающая последовательность, полученная при объединении последовательностей A и B. Если существует некоторое число, которое встречается и в последовательности A, и в последовательности B, то в последовательность C это число попадает в единственном экземпляре.

Входные данные
В единственной строке входного файла дано натуральное число x (1 ≤ x ≤ 10<sup>7</sup>).

Выходные данные
В выходной файл выведите C<sub>x</sub>.

Примеры
входные данные
1
выходные данные
1

входные данные
2
выходные данные
4

входные данные
4
выходные данные
9

```
x = int(input())

c = []

for i in range(x+2):

    c.append(i**2)
    c.append(i**3)

c = list(set(c))

c.sort()

print(c[x])
```

Comment: и сколько выполняется данный код по времени?

Comment: время я не знаю, знаю только что долго, теперь я убрал set так как он тормозит прогу но все равно не проходит

Comment: x = int(input())
    c = []
    for i in range(x+2):
        c.append(i**2)
        c.append(i**3)
    c = list(c)

from itertools import groupby

    new_x = [el for el, _ in groupby(c)]

    print(new_x[x])

Comment: текст задачи добавьте

Comment: А цель-то какая?

Comment: добавьте ещё какие там ограничения по скорости ?

Comment: @Интик Везде для этой задачи встречается ограничение 1 секунда. При этом кроме Python'а языки указаны все что можно, типа C++, Pascal и т.п.. Что, как мне кажется, не сопоставимо. У меня 10^7 посчитало за 2.3 секунды на компе 10-тилетней давности.

Comment: Не надо минусить отличную задачу. За одну секунду можно вычислить число с номером 10^58.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так раза в полтора быстрее. Только смысл?

```
c = set()
for i in range(x+2):
    i2 = i*i
    c.add(i2)
    c.add(i2*i)

c = sorted(c)
```

**UPD** Если нужен только последний элемент, то хранить всю последовательность (а тем более её сортировать) вовсе не нужно. Можно просто вычислить этот элемент.
Вот так на порядок быстрее:

```
def get_cx(x):
    i, j = 1, 1
    i2, j3 = 1, 1 # i**2, j**3
    k = 1
    while k <= x:
        if i2 == j3:
            i += 1
            i2 = i*i
            k -= 1
        elif i2 < j3:
            res = i2
            i += 1
            i2 = i*i
        else: # i2 > j3
            res = j3
            j += 1
            j3 = j*j*j
        k += 1

    return res
```

Comment: смысл в том что я забиваю прогу, а она не проходит по времени даже представленная вами выше

Comment: я исправил задачу взгляните

Comment: @АлександрКоролев Ок, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Всем спасибо, задача прошла

Answer (score 3):

Очень красивая классная задача. Решается немного длинно, зато решение очень быстрое.

В формулировке задачи определена возрастающая последовательность `C(i)` и требуется вычислить определённый её элемент. Номер элемента не превосходит `10^7`, что позволяет построить всю последовательность до нужного элемента за время сравнимое с одной секундой. Это простое решение, но это ложный след. `C(i)` можно вычислить не строя все предшествующие элементы.

**Математика**

В пару к функции `n = C(i)` определим функцию `i = D(n)` - количество элементов последовательности `C` не больших чем `n`. `D(n)` не убывает.

По `i` отыщем `k` такое что `D(2^k) < i <= D(2^(k + 1))`. Затем двоичным поиском отыщем `n` такое что `D(n - 1) < i <= D(n)`. Тогда верно что `С(i) = n`.

Как вычислить `D(n)`? Нужно сложить количество полных квадратов не больших `n` и количество полных кубов. При этом некоторые числа мы учтём два раза. Это числа которые и квадраты и кубы. Можно убедится что все такие числа - шестые степени. Определим функцию `root(n, b)` - число степеней порядка `b` не превосходящих `n`. Тогда `D(n) = root(n, 2) + root(n, 3) - root(n, 6)`.

Функция `root(n, b)` вычисляется аналогично `C(i)`: отыщем `k` такое что `(2^k)^b <= n < (2^(k + 1))^b`. Двоичным поиском отыщем `r` такое что `r^b <= n < (r + 1)^b`. `r` - искомое значение.

Функцию `root` можно вычислить с помощью вещественной арифметики и после уточнить, я выбрал другой способ чтобы не иметь проблем с точностью и ограниченной разрядностью вещественных чисел.

**Код**

```
def bsearch(n, f):
    low = 1
    high = 2
    while f(high) <= n:
        low, high = high, 2 * high
    assert f(low) <= n < f(high)
    
    while low < high - 1:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        assert low < mid < high
        if f(mid) <= n:
            low = mid
        else:
            high = mid
        assert f(low) <= n < f(high)
    assert low + 1 == high

    return low


def root(n, b):
    return bsearch(n, lambda i: i ** b)


def d(n):
    return root(n, 2) + root(n, 3) - root(n, 6)


def c(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return bsearch(n - 1, d) + 1


print(c(int(input())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 | python ith_item.py
> 1
>
> $ echo 4 | python ith_item.py
> 9
>
> $ time echo 10000000 | python ith_item.py
> 99080961339364
>
> real  0m0.033s
> user  0m0.028s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

**P.S.** Обнаружилась закономерность:

> ```
>     i C(i)
>     1 1
> 10^ 3 837225
> 10^ 6 980426727225
> 10^ 9 998004326672772225
> 10^12 999800043326667277722225
> 10^15 999980000433326666727777222225
> 10^18 999998000004333326666672777772222225
> 10^21 999999800000043333326666667277777722222225
> 10^24 999999980000000433333326666666727777777222222225
> 10^27 999999998000000004333333326666666672777777772222222225
> 10^30 999999999800000000043333333326666666667277777777722222222225
> 10^33 999999999980000000000433333333326666666666727777777777222222222225
> 10^36 999999999998000000000004333333333326666666666672777777777772222222222225
> 10^39 999999999999800000000000043333333333326666666666667277777777777722222222222225
> 10^42 999999999999980000000000000433333333333326666666666666727777777777777222222222222225
> 10^45 999999999999998000000000000004333333333333326666666666666672777777777777772222222222222225
> 10^48 999999999999999800000000000000043333333333333326666666666666667277777777777777722222222222222225
> 10^51 999999999999999980000000000000000433333333333333326666666666666666727777777777777777222222222222222225
> 10^54 999999999999999998000000000000000004333333333333333326666666666666666672777777777777777772222222222222222225
> ```